# UnicodeDecodeError when running pip install

Tags: python

I made a setup.py for my python project including the following line:

```
scripts=['gps-sdr-sim', 'player/limeplayer', 'satgen/nmea2um'],
```

Without this line, everything runs perfectly, so I assume this is where the problems start.
With this line I get the following output when running `pip3 install -e .`

```
Obtaining file:///home/dennis/Dokumente/gps/src/gps-sdr-sim
Installing collected packages: gps-sdr-sim
  Attempting uninstall: gps-sdr-sim
    Found existing installation: gps-sdr-sim 1.0
    Uninstalling gps-sdr-sim-1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled gps-sdr-sim-1.0
  Running setup.py develop for gps-sdr-sim
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/dennis/Dokumente/gps/src/gps-sdr-sim/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/dennis/Dokumente/gps/src/gps-sdr-sim/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix=                                                    
         cwd: /home/dennis/Dokumente/gps/src/gps-sdr-sim/                                                           
    Complete output (33 lines):                                                                                     
    running develop                                                                                                 
    running egg_info                                                                                                
    writing gps_sdr_sim.egg-info/PKG-INFO                                                                           
    writing dependency_links to gps_sdr_sim.egg-info/dependency_links.txt                                           
    writing top-level names to gps_sdr_sim.egg-info/top_level.txt                                                   
    reading manifest file 'gps_sdr_sim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                        
    writing manifest file 'gps_sdr_sim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                        
    running build_ext                                                                                               
    Creating /home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gps-sdr-sim.egg-link (link to .)                       
    Adding gps-sdr-sim 1.0 to easy-install.pth file                                                                 
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                              
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                          
      File "/home/dennis/Dokumente/gps/src/gps-sdr-sim/setup.py", line 21, in <module>                              
        setuptools.setup(                                                                                           
      File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup             
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)                                                                        
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup                                               
        dist.run_commands()                                                                                         
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 34, in run
        self.install_for_development()
      File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 151, in install_for_development
        self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
      File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 722, in process_distribution
        self.install_egg_scripts(dist)
      File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 186, in install_egg_scripts
        script_text = strm.read()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 40: invalid start byte
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of gps-sdr-sim
  Moving to /home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gps-sdr-sim.egg-link
   from /tmp/pip-uninstall-orbm7q8o/gps-sdr-sim.egg-link
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/dennis/Dokumente/gps/src/gps-sdr-sim/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/dennis/Dokumente/gps/src/gps-sdr-sim/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you tried raw strings? I.e.:
    `scripts=[r'gps-sdr-sim', r'player/limeplayer', r'satgen/nmea2um'],`

Comment: @lunesco yeah I tried but that throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to fix the problem directly.It might be that the scripts must be python files. I used the following workaround to include the gps-sdr-sim, limeplayer and nmea2um programs